# Generate a 2D list based on probability

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate an `n`-row list where each row is `k` columns.
Then order is based on probability.

Given: `L = [1, 2, 3]` and the probability list `P = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]`,

Expected output based on the probability:

```
[[3, 3],[3, 1],[1, 3],[3, 2],[2, 3],[1, 1]]
```

where `[3,3]` is the first since it yields the highest probability of `1.0`.
second is `[3,1]` with `0.8` and so on.

Here's my code:

```
L = [3, 1, 2]        # Input List
P = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]  # Probability List
k = 2                # 2 columns per row
n = 6                # 6 rows in 2D array

nL = np.array(L)

generated_list = np.zeros(shape=(1, k), dtype=int)
while generated_list.shape[0] != n:
    choice = np.random.choice(L, size=k, p=P)
    if not np.any(generated_list == [choice]):
        generated_list = np.append(generated_list, [choice], axis=0)
```

I can't seem to have an ordered list based on probability.
It also contains duplicate elements.

Sample `generated_list` output:

```
[[0, 0],[3, 1],[2, 3],[1, 2],[2, 3],[2, 3]]
```

What's the best way to do this:
1. Compare if a 1-D element is already in 2-D array
2. Have the random choice return first the highest probability combination

Comment: "random choice return first the highest probability combination" you do realize that "random" inherently means you can't perfectly define what it will return first.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, yes I have realized. so perhaps there's no `numpy` way of doing such.

Comment: It's not that there is no way to do it with numpy, it's that what you are asking for isn't random data.

Comment: You usually multiply probabilities not add, so isn't `[3, 3]` a probability of `0.25`?

Comment: @AChampion,  list `P` will sum up to `1` if you add all elements. for my case, I'm concerned with the probability for each element and wanted to generate a `k`-list where there sum of probabilities will yield the most. for the example, where `3` has `0.5` probability based on the list. and `[3, 3]` has the highest sum of probabilities which is `1`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, see what you mean. I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, with a little help of [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

L = [1, 2, 3]
P = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]

n = 2
k = 6

probs = dict(zip(L, P))

result = sorted(list(product(L, repeat=n)), key=lambda x: (sum(probs[i] for i in x), [probs[i] for i in x]), reverse=True)[:k]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted`:

```
l = [[0, 0],[3, 1],[2, 3],[1, 2],[2, 3],[2, 3]]
p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5]
sorted(l, key= lambda x: sum(p[v] for v in x))
```

returns:

```
[[3, 1], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2], [0, 0]]
```

(I assumed that you had 4 different probabilities as your `generated_list` has indexes 0 to 3)